Unable to set Cache-Control header in Laravel
I'm having an issue with setting the Cache-Control header in my Laravel application. No matter what I try, the browser always shows the following header:
Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-cache, no-store, private

I've created a custom middleware called \App\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders that looks like this:
class SetCacheHeaders
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        if ($response instanceof \Illuminate\Http\Response) {
            $response->header('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=7200');
            $response->setEtag(md5($response->getContent()));
        }

        return $response;
    }
}

I've also tried using the predefined Laravel middleware:
->middleware('cache.headers:public;max_age=7200;etag');

However, in both cases, only the Etag header is being set, and the Cache-Control header is not being modified.
I've read that this issue can be caused by PHP settings, so I've also updated my php.ini file to set session.cache_limiter = ''.
This application is hosted using Laravel Forge, so I'm wondering if that could be causing any issues with the cache settings.
I also tried setting the Cache-Control header directly in the Nginx configuration, which worked, but in this case, I ended up with two Cache-Control headers, which is not ideal.
Could you please help me understand why I'm unable to control the Cache-Control header in my Laravel application? I need to set the Back/forward cache functionality, and this is preventing me from doing so.
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Could you add your response function from the Controller?

Sure, it's just simple view return. return view('homepage');

In Middleware, you should set headers on the Response.
Tested it on Laravel 11, even tried to overwrite in the controller, but Middleware overwrites it.
    $response->headers->set('header', 'value');

So, with your code, it should look like this:
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class SetCacheHeaders
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        if ($response instanceof Response)
        {
            $response->header->set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=7200');
            $response->header->set('ETag', md5($response->getContent()));
        }

        return $response;
    }
}


Your example works on Laravel 11. I tried to set it up the same way in my current project which runs on Laravel 10. Unfortunately, the changes didn't take effect here.

There is a typo in this example; the response has a headers property, not a header property,
So the example should look like $response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=7200'); and $response->headers->set('ETag', md5($response->getContent()));
This should work on all versions of Laravel.
